# wso2am and https request

Tags: https, wso2

Good day! I am using wso2am-3.2.0 I created an API (Design a New REST API) where Endpoint is an https server. Server technical support provides two certificates: cacer.p7b and ssl.croinform.cer. I was able to convert cacer.p7, getting two .cer format certificates (unfortunately, I got two files). I have added all three certificates to Endpoint. However, the queries still don't work.
My requests work directly to the API service, but through WSO2 I get an error. Also, technical support recommends setting up an openssl analog for curl. Apparently, you need to do the same for wso2.
Error:

```
Endpoint: test - v1.0_APIproduction The endpoint with the address https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test will be marked PUSHED as it failed.
Pause endpoint: test - v1.0_APIproductionEndpoint with the address https://ssl.croinform.ru:450/api.test - last pause duration was: 30,000ms and current pause duration: 30,000ms - Next try after: wednesday 01 September 09:13:20 UTC 2021
{api: admin - test: v1.0} STATUS = The default error sequence is running, ERROR_CODE = 101500, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in sender.
```

a) Tell me how can I fix this error?
b) Perhaps you need to configure encryption?
c) Does WSO2-am use openssl for encryption?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try in the pem format?

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.